# Unknown primary key for table report_merge_holders in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class GenerateReportControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

 setup do
  @client = clients(:one)    
  @results = report_merge_holders(:one)
 end

In `fixtures/report_merge_holders.yml`:
   one:
    id: 1
    client_id: "1"
    FOLIO_NO: "12323"

In `fixtures/clients.yml`:
   one:
    id: 1
    isin_number: "SDS232"
    code: "232DD"
    name: "KJHSFDKJ"
```

I am new in "unit-testing".I want to set "client_id" to 1.I am getting error like `"ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table report_merge_holders in model ReportMergeHolder"`.Please help me out.

Comment: `self.primary_key = :id` in the model `ReportMergeHolder`

Comment: not test model but app/models folder consist the file.... there is the model

Comment: I think it's not the right way to solve this issue, code should be modified in "test" folder. Can i set primary key in "setup" in "GenerateReportControllerTest".

Comment: did you see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to specify the primary ID as `:id` if your tables are correctly created. Have a look your schema.rb file and check whether the `report_merge_holders` has `id: false` in the `create_table` function. Remove `id: false`if it's present and things should work.

Comment: "report_merge_holders" is a view table that i am using.